# SimpleInjector lifestyle.CreateInstance per webrequest

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I am trying to register a `DBContext` that implements two interfaces for a web application. I want to create a `WebRequestLifestyle` registration, with Simple Iinjector I now get an exception on load about torn registration (I think that I was previously getting multiple instances but I didn't mind). Following [this example](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tornlifestyle.html) from the documentation, I get an error about a Lifestyle mismatch. When I do `lifestyle.CreateRegistration` in on a `WebRequestLifestyle` instance, I always get transient context registration.

Question: How do I get `LifeStyle.CreateRegistration` to return me a per web request registration rather than a transient registration?

**Edit**

```
namespace SIProject.Sample.Web.Controllers
{
public class Taxonomy{
    public int TaxonomyId { get; set; }
    public string Term { get; set; }
}

public class NavItem
{
    public int NavItemId { get; set; }
    public string NavName { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public interface ITaxonomyDBContext
{
    DbSet<Taxonomy> Taxonomys { get; set; }
}

public interface INavigationDBContext
{
    DbSet<NavItem> NavItems { get; set; } 
}

public class MyDBContext : IdentityDbContext, ITaxonomyDBContext, INavigationDBContext
{
    public DbSet<Taxonomy> Taxonomys { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NavItem> NavItems { get; set; }
}

public class MyService
{

    public MyService(MyDBContext dbContext)
    {

    }
}

public class ServiceB
{
    public ServiceB(MyDBContext dbContext)
    {

    }
}
}
```

and my global.asax is

```
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterServices();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    private void RegisterServices()
    {
        Container container = new Container();

        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

        container.Register<ITaxonomyDBContext, MyDBContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<INavigationDBContext, MyDBContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);


        container.Verify();
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to register the dbcontext so that I get a single DBContext across all services?

Answer (score 1):

My Brain woke up this morning and realised my mistake

here is the answer for reference:

```
private void RegisterServices()
{
    Container container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

    var registration = container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle.CreateRegistration<MyDBContext>(container);

    container.AddRegistration(typeof(ITaxonomyDBContext), registration);
    container.AddRegistration(typeof(INavigationDBContext), registration);

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));

    container.Verify();
}
```